# setShowsAsAction not working below API 11

Tags: android, android-menu

This is the code I used to remove a `MenuItem`:

```
af.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
```

However, `setShowsAsAction` requires minimum API 11 so it crashes on GingerBread. I can use `af.setVisible(false);` to get the code to work on GingerBread. What are the differences between the two? Is it the same thing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the v7 support library as followed:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(....);
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem , MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1. af.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
```

This will cause the MenuItem to be hidden fro the ActionBar. However it will be visible in the OverFlow Menu.

```
2. af.setVisible(false);
```

This will hide the MenuItem completely from the ActionBar and the Overflow Menu as well.

Answer (score 1):

The difference might be when you set `showAsAction` to `never`, your menu item is still accessible with menu hardware or overflow button in `ActionBar` whereas when you use set `visible` method, your menu item is not displayed, even if you press the menu.

According to the reference, `setVisible(boolean visible)`:

> Sets the visibility of the MenuItem. If true the item will be visible; if false it is hidden (added in API 1)

And `showAsAction` method:

> Sets how this item should display in the presence of an Action Bar (added in API 11)

As you can read, the mostly difference is `showAsAction="never"` is related to the `ActionBar` and hiding on it but still showing in overflow menu whereas `setVisible` since API 1 doesn't care about overflow menu and `ActionBar`: set to false, it litteraly hide your menu item.